# How do I wait for a reply in Discord.net

Tags: c#, bots, discord.net

I am creating a Discord bot using Discord.net. I would like to add some commands that would require multiple steps for a command. An example of this would be a command like "+give". Once the user has typed "+give", I would like the bot to respond by saying something along the lines of, "how much". The user would reply how many points they would like to give (points have already been implemented), and then the bot will say "to who?" and the user will reply with a person in the server. I have tried quite a few solutions, but none of them have worked. If anyone has any idea how to do this, that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use a command give [amountToGive] [userToReceive].
AmountToGive could be 500 or any other number 
UserToReceive, the user which would receive the amount. 
No need for a multi step approach at all

Comment: @Exitare Yes I definitely could do that in this case, however I am asking this as more of a general purpose question. The give command was just an example to show what it is I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You'd need to use one of the interactive addons. There isn't a built in way to wait for events in a command. Example https://github.com/d4n3436/Fergun.Interactive

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to make 2 commands, like +give and +amount. Then, make a variable that turns true when you use the command +give. Use an if statement to then see if you can use +amount.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I'll try and implement that.